# Remove item from List that I'm iterating, or filtering complex List of duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logic

Ok, maybe I'm just blind, but answer is eluding me:

so, model:

```
public class Dimensions
{
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public int PeacesForItem { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a method that is filtering the List:

```
public List<Dimensions> Consolidation(List<Dimensions> vm)
    {
        var list = new List<Dimensions>();
        if (vm != null)
        {
            var typeIds = vm.Select(x => x.TypeId).ToHashSet();
            foreach (var t in typeIds)
            {
                foreach(var item in vm)
                {
                    if (t == item.IvericaId)
                    {
                        int x = 0;
                        foreach (var again in vm)
                        {
                            if (item.Duzina == again.Duzina && item.Sirina == again.Sirina && item.TypeId== again.TypeId)
                            {
                                x ++;
                                // vm.Remove(item); Not working, who would figure 
                            }
                        }
                        list.Add(
                            new Dimensions
                            {
                                Width = item.Width,
                                Height = item.Height,
                                TypeId= item.TypeId,
                                PeacesForItem = x * item.PeacesForItem,
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

This method is iterating thru List items and checks if there are elements of same dimensions. If there are, then it is doubling needed quantity.

QUESTION: This code is still adding duplicates to new list, and I need to filter that out.

I tried numerous approaches, but every one I came up with has some fatal flaw in the design.

Comment: Which type of data is in your list ? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser `var list = new List<Dimensions>();`

Comment: use a for loop and removeAt(i--) (foreach has an iterator object that causes the error when the list contents change)

Comment: @sQuir3l You can still use `foreach` by iterating a copy of the list e.g. `foreach(var foo in bar.ToList())` etc...

Comment: why not use the extensionMethod DIstinct()? Like this List<Dimension> onlyDifferentValuesList = orginalList.Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public List<Dimensions> Consolidation(List<Dimensions> vm)
{
    return vm.GroupBy(d=>new {d.TypeId, d.Width, d.Height}) // if there are any duplicates, they are grouped here
            .Select(g=>new Dimensions(){TypeId = g.Key.TypeId , 
                                        Width = g.Key.Width, 
                                        Height = g.Key.Height,
                                        PeacesForItem = g.Sum(dim=>dim.PeacesForItem)}) // number of duplicates in group calculated
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes. So much cleaner.

Comment: I was not aware of GroupBy extension. This is very powerful and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You've massively over-complicated this one :). You don't need the nested loop, plus you're not doubling the value, you're **squaring** it? Try this:

```
var list = new List<Dimensions>();
if (vm != null)
{
    foreach (var item in vm)
    {
        //Not sure how you identify dupes, may need to change the filter here
        var duplicate = vm
            .Where(v => v.PeacesForItem == item.PeacesForItem);

        if (dupes.Any())
        {
            list.Add(new Dimension
            {
                 Width = item.Width,
                 Height = item.Height,
                 TypeId = item.TypeId,
                 PeacesForItem = item.PeacesForItem * 2;
            });
        }
    }
}
return list;
```

Comment: I think this would not work (my code is simplification of the problem), but it is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

dublicate the vm-List and iterate over the duplicated list and delete the object form the original list

```
public List<Dimensions> Consolidation(List<Dimensions> vm)
    {
        var list = new List<Dimensions>();


        if (vm != null)
        {
            var dublicate = new List<Dimensions>(vm);
            var typeIds = vm.Select(x => x.TypeId).ToHashSet();
            foreach (var t in typeIds)
            {
                foreach(var item in dublicate )
                {
                    if (t == item.IvericaId)
                    {
                        int x = 0;
                        foreach (var again in dublicate )
                        {
                            if (item.Duzina == again.Duzina && item.Sirina == again.Sirina && item.TypeId== again.TypeId)
                            {
                                x ++;
                                vm.Remove(item); //Now working 
                            }
                        }
                        list.Add(
                            new Dimensions
                            {
                                Width = item.Width,
                                Height = item.Height,
                                TypeId= item.TypeId,
                                PeacesForItem = x * item.PeacesForItem,
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```